# Don't know how Ajax - "result" to place in @foreach() - [in a Laravel project]

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I don't know how to use "result" array in @foreach()
Please tell me what is wrong in it.
And is there any better way to do this ?
This is in a Laravel 5.2 project

```js
success:function(result){
    //alert(result);
    $('#sub_category_select').html(
    +'  <option value="">--- Sub Category ---</option>'
    +'  @foreach('result' as $subCategoryItem)'
    +'  <option value="{{$subCategoryItem->id}}">{{$subCategoryItem->category}}</option>'
    +'  @endforeach'
    );
}
```

The result is coming from the controller below -

```js
public function subCategorySelect(){
    $category_id = trim(Input::get('category_id'));
    $subCategoryData = DB::table('categories')
        ->where('parent_id',$category_id)
        ->get();
    return $subCategoryData;
}
```

Please help me...............

Comment: __Wrong__ is that you don't understand web basics and mix php-templating with javascript execution.

Comment: yes, I think there is some wrong in [ +'  @foreach('result' as $subCategoryItem)' ] this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well mainly it's impossible becouse AJAX request is the part of the client side such as JavaScript and blade templates are the part of server side such as PHP. So what you can do is, create a blade template with:

```
<option value="">--- Sub Category ---</option>'
@foreach($result as $subCategoryItem)'
    <option value="{{$subCategoryItem->id}}">{{$subCategoryItem->category}}</option>
@endforeach'
```

then you have to retunr this template for AJAX request (in routes.php):

```
Routes::get('sub_items', function () {
    $results = //here you have to recive categories somehow
    return view('the_template_above', compact('results'));
});
```

And the the JS part will looks like:

```
success:function(result){
    //alert(result);
    $('#sub_category_select').html(result);
}
```

Comment: where to put "return view('the_template_above');" ? how this will be triggered ?

Comment: You have some ajax request right? It points to some route (routes.php) in your system. I will reedit my entry to show you how to achive this in routes.

Comment: no, it's showing - Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Ok, I reedit again... you need to recive the collection or array `$results` with subcategories (on server side).

Comment: According to your concept, I made another blade template, and in controller, I wrote -         return View::make('subcat-select-on-title-page')
            ->with('subCategories',$subCategoryData);
And in ajax part - $('#sub_category_select').html(result); - It working fine. So, is it good ? can I go for it ?

Comment: Yes you can - it's even better to use controllers in your application to be all put together in the right way (MVC like)

Comment: so, the concept now - I am returning all the html part along with the foreach() and then showing in sub_category_select div by $('#sub_category_select').html(result); - IS THIS THE CONCEPT ?

Comment: Hope it will not create any problem ?

Comment: No it won't brings any problems. It's a AJAX concept - you're making request to the server and in the response you get a part of html code - it's OK. the other way to solve this is to get a plain data from the reqest and cover it in html tag inside JS.

Comment: yes, that is the thing I wanted to do, that's why I made the category array in controller, and returned in ajax (on view page) and tried to loop foreach for that array.

Answer (score 1):

```
controller:-
    public function subCategorySelect(){
        $category_id = trim(Input::get('category_id'));
        $subCategoryData = DB::table('categories')
            ->where('parent_id',$category_id)
            ->get();
            return $subCategoryData->result();
            echo $this->load->view('path_of_new_view_php_file',subCategoryData );
        }

view File-
    <option value="">--- Sub Category ---</option>'
    <?php
        foreach('result' as $subCategoryItem){
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $subCategoryItem->id}}">
        <?php echo $subCategoryItem->categor ?>
    </option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
js part:-
    function(category_id){
    $.get('Controller_path/subCategorySelect',
    {
       category_id: category_id
    },
    function (data,status) {
       if (status == "success") {
       $('#sub_category_select').html(result);
     }
   });
  }
```